# How does Apache parse DN from X509

Tags: apache, x509, pki

I have a version of an application that uses PKI (X509) for authentication/authorization. In an older version of apache (2.2) the DN is delimited by forward slashes (/), in the version of apache (2.4) on my new box the DN for the SAME CERTIFICATE is delimited by commas (,).

What tool does Apache use to parse the DN out of the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the tool/library that Apache uses, but a certificate itself doesn't use delimiters.

The whole certificate is formatted in asn1 which is a tree structure right down to the components of the DN in the subject name field.

The delimiters are very likely only relevant for display purposes.